# Openpyxl, Pandas or xlrd for correct data representation?

Tags: python, database, excel

I have an Excel file and I need to rearrange data inside of it according to some conditions. I need to group data and save relationship between rows and cols, also I need to merge some cells, containing the same given name (in the example that's "condition").

So what's the best way to do this? Totally lost.

For instance, input is:

```
"ID" "NAME" "CONDITION 1" "CONDITION 2" "CONDITION 3"
"0" "CLARK" "ALIEN"       "JOURNALIST"  "HERO"
"1" "BRUCE" "JUSTICE"     "MILLIONAIRE" "BAT"
```

And output should be:

```
"CLARK" "ALIEN, JOURNALIST, HERO"
"BRUCE" "JUSTICE, MILLIONAIRE, BAT"
```

Any help, thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to import this database to MySQL Workbench but encountering an error all the time. I've imported it to *.csv file.

Comment: Are you looking to concatenate each row of two columns? And do you want to do this in a Python package, or via Excel/VBA? Are you using one of the packages in your question title?

Comment: First of all, I would like to use something similar to GROUP_BY, because it's necessity for this particular task, and I am looking to concatenate each row containing specific word. I have no idea what's the best approach to do it, that's why I'm here. I already successfully installed all the packages, but those are for reading and writing files, but not for manipulating, as I can understand.

Comment: To little data to follow your needs, please expand.

Comment: If your data isn't sensitive, could you post it, or at least some screenshots?

Comment: Any of the three packages you listed are fine for reading Excel files. Once read, the data can be fairly easily manipulated with the functionality built into the Python language. But so far the question isn't precise enough. Is your difficulty that you don't know how to concatenate values in Python? Is it that you don't know how to make the program pick out which columns need to be grouped together? Do you have to group some columns named "FOO 1", "FOO 2", "FOO 3", and "FOO 4", and other columns named "BAR 1" and "BAR 2"?

Answer (score 0):

I've attempted to replicate your problem in Excel.

[image]

Here's the above with formulas displayed:

[image]

That is, the concatenation formula is `=CONCATENATE(B2," ",C2)`, etc.

I'm not familiar with the Python packages you refer to, but it's worth adding those specific tags to bring this to the attention of those that are. In that case I'd suggest focusing the question a bit more.